# PrimeNG Menubar items are not even

Tags: css, angular, primeng

I've added a minimal PrimeNG Menubar instance to an app I'm working on. But when the app renders, the menubar items (there are only two) are uneven; i.e., the items render in order but the first item is lower than the second item.

The relevant code follows:

The Angular component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MenuItem } from 'primeng/api';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-menubar',
  templateUrl: './menubar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./menubar.component.css']
})
export class MenubarComponent implements OnInit {
  CORE_MENU_ITEMS: MenuItem[] = [
    {
      label: 'Home',
      icon: 'fa fa-home',
      routerLink: ['/home'],
    },
    {
      label: 'Comics',
      icon: 'fa fa-book',
      items: [
        {
          label: 'Library',
          icon: 'fas fa-book-reader',
          routerLink: ['/comics'],
        },
        {
          label: 'Import',
          icon: 'fas fa-file-upload',
          routerLink: ['/import'],
        },
      ]
    }
  ];

  protected items: MenuItem[];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.items = this.CORE_MENU_ITEMS;
  }
}
```

The component HTML:

```
<p-menubar styleClass='border-0' [model]='items' [autoDisplay]='false'>
</p-menubar>
```

In .angular-cli.json I've added:

```
"prefix": "app",
    "styles": [
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
    "../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
    "../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/start/theme.css",
    "../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css",
    "styles.scss"
],
```

And here's a screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Are you able to create a StackBlitz that reproduces the issue?

Comment: I think you forgot to add CSS like this in style.css   import "~primeng/resources/primeng.min.css";
  import "~primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css";

Comment: @PareshGami I have included it. Added it to the post above.

Comment: @user184994 I can try to pare it down a bit.

Comment: It seems to be related to the submenu items since, when I remove them and just have it be the "Home" and "Comics" menu then everything lines up correctly.

Comment: One more comment: I just noticed that this ONLY shows up in Chrome 70: I tried it in Firefox 63 and it works correctly.